# Doxygen - document function created with macros

Tags: function, macros, doxygen

Does anyone know how to document this function with doxygen?

```
FUNC( void, CODE ) functionName( bool argument );
```

Comment: How is the defintion of the macro? Need some more information about the context.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution. 
In config file of doxygen for this code,
I changed this 3 line:

```
MACRO_EXPANSION       = YES
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF    = YES
PREDEFINED            = "FUNC(rettype, memclass) = rettype"
```