# #defined enum on Doxygen

Tags: c++, enums, macros, doxygen

So I have a `#define` that creates a "MY_ENUM"  (minimal version)

```
#define MY_ENUM(ename, ...)              \                                                
  namespace ename {                      \
    enum ename { __VA_ARGS__, COUNT };   \
    static std::string _Strings[COUNT];  \
    static inline size_t size() {return COUNT;}  \ 
}
```

This generates useful enums that can be created as:

```
/**
  * @brief List of elements
  */
MY_ENUM(enuElements, Element1, Element2, Element3, Element4, Element5, Element6)
```

But generating the doc with doxygen doesn't seem to work => it mixes one enum with the following and some don't even appear.

I set:

```
MACRO_EXPANSION        = YES
SKIP_FUNCTION_MACROS   = NO
PREDEFINED             = MY_ENUM(x) =
```

For what I have read, the answer is a proper setting of `PREDEFINED` but I haven't achieved, does anyone know how to create a document with this kind of defines?

**Edit**

Doxygen Version :  1.8.0

About why I think the clue is in `PREDEFINED` (but I might as well be wrong):

- The [site of Doxygen when talking about macros](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/preprocessing.html)
- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58404171/11261546) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34093832/11261546) questions on SO

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Setting `PREDEFINED = MY_ENUM(x) =`  in your settings file is a bit strange when you want to have the real setting, where did you read about the: "the answer is a proper setting of PREDEFINED"? Please can you expand your code samples to a complete example so we can do some testing.

Comment: Editing right now ... :)

Comment: @albert I added stuff to the question

Comment: Well version 1.8.0 is very old (February 2012) so I definitely advise you to update to a newer version (current version is 1.9.1). With version 1.9.1 I have no problems, just see to it that the \ is the last character on the line! (in the example there are spaces behind it, might be from cut / paste though). I didn't set `PREDEFINED` as this is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks @albert I'll try with a different version, just out of curiosity, did you get a nice printed list? or did Doxygen treated it as a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following code:

```
/// \file

#define MY_ENUM(ename, ...)              \
  namespace ename {                      \
    enum ename { __VA_ARGS__, COUNT };   \
    static std::string _Strings[COUNT];  \
    static inline size_t size() {return COUNT;}  \
}

/**
  * @brief List of elements
  */
MY_ENUM(enuElements, Element1, Element2, Element3, Element4, Element5, Element6)
```

The setting (besides the default settings):

```
MACRO_EXPANSION        = YES
```

and doxygen 1.9.1 I got:

[image]